# Need a function to determine an object's rotation axis, based on it's orientation

Tags: python, coordinates

Working on a project with some Python scripting to allow users to flip an object on any axis, and then use a routine that will rotate the object along the circle as shown in the pic below.
My problem is I need a function that will return "X", "Y", or "Z" to indicate the resulting normal axis to rotate around , based on the objects current position in the scene, after user manipulation.[image]

Comment: I'm using the following rotate command to rotate the object along the circle line, but need to know the "orient_axis"  to rotate around.   bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=radians(deg_rot), orient_axis='Y', orient_type='NORMAL')

Comment: Its a bit unclear to me. What are the rules to determinate this axis depending on object position? Is the question about finding the axis or rotating, both?

Comment: the question is about finding the axis of rotation.  Rotating the object along the circle is the easy part.  After the program manipulates the object in place (flipping x, y, z multiple times, finding the axis of rotation is the ultimate goal)  I have tested this extensively and the axis of rotation will change based on order of local flipping of the object.  I'm looking for a formula that will derive the axis of rotation based on the objects current orientation.